# ThreadSafe scenario/feature context

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I am having trouble adding the ability to call the feature and scenario contexts when running the framework in parallel.

I have looked over

http://specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/

but I am still having trouble understanding how to actually add this to the framework.

Does anyone have an example of this working in practice?

I am trying to create a report using

> ParentNode = Extent.CreateTest(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title);

but I cant call this when running in parallel, any help on getting this thread safe will be extremely welcome

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms you cannot call `FeatureContext.Current` or `ScenarioContext.Current` in parallel.

instead ask for an instance of either `FeatureContext` or `ScenarioContext` in the constructor of the steps class that you want to use it in, and Specflows DI container will give you the current one for the currently executing test, and you can then store that as a field in your class and use that field safely.