# C# Specflow - Need Feature and Scenario Title without using FeatureContext and ScenarioContext

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, context-injection

I have a hooks.cs Binding file which have BeforeTestRun, BeforeFeature and BeforeScenario. I need Title of current Feature and scenario for log and report purposes. Since I am running the test in parallel, ScenarioContext throws exception as:

> The ScenarioContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-threaded execution...

Is there any way that I could get the current feature title and scenario title in multi-threaded execution?

Comment: This question is technically a duplicate, but the question and answer aren't as good: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48586809/3092298

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can get the current FeatureContext and ScenarioContext by getting it via constructor injection.

```
public class MyBindingClass
{
  private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

  public MyBindingClass(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
  {
    this.scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
  }

  [When("I say hello to ScenarioContext")]
  public void WhenISayHello()
  {
    // access scenarioContext here
  }
}
```

See https://specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/ - Injecting ScenarioContext at the bottom.